# style content within an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have to style something within an iframe.

```
<html>
 <head>
   <link href="url/to/my/custom.css"></link>
 </head>
 <body>
    ......
    <iframe class="webform-frame">...</iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

In my custom.css I already tried to use `.webform-frame h5 { color: #f00; }` but it doesn't work.

The iframe is generated by some JavaScript (I have no access to it).

Any idea how I could style that stuff within that iframe?

Comment: The document inside the `iframe` is a separate document; you'll need to add your style sheet there. Either in the HTML, or dynamically using JavaScript (but for that the iframe's document needs to be on the same domain. Is it?)

Comment: no its on a different domain

Comment: Usually what companies do (I'm sure you will have seen it) is enclose the iFrame in your own wrapping document. Companies do this when they require you to make a payment. They have their company logo and style in your document, and the payment form is in a separate iFrame within this. No, you can't style the stuff in that iFrame, but you can style your own code around it. Perhaps think more toward this standard solution employed by many enterprise companies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS to iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to target the `iframe` i.e the border, border color, padding, or margin, then using this will target your `iframe`:

```
iframe.webform-frame {
   /* Styles */
}
```

If you are trying to target the markup which is loaded inside the `iframe` than that's not possible.

> Note: You can control a few things like making the frame background transparent etc...

---

> Edit: Would like to add `seamless` attribute explanation here, as Sebastian told, but the
>   support is poor, you should perhaps ignore doing so.. Also do not edit
>   any iframed pages without prior permission of the page owner

Comment: My solution is perfectly valid for some special purposes (e.g. Chrome extension development) and I think it shouldn't be ignored if the use case allows it.

Comment: to work around CORS you may be able to add a <script> tag into the child iframe which then loads a javascript file that calls out to the parent and setup some sort of callback. Think of it like JSONP but for frames. This is off the top of my head so YMMV

Answer (score 6):

There is a new HTML 5 feature called [seamless](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-seamless) iframe, which perhaps does what you want:

> [...] it indicates that the iframe element's browsing context is to be rendered in a manner that makes it appear to be part of the containing document [...]

```
<iframe src="iframe.html" seamless></iframe>
```

However, for now it has very poor browser support (Webkit only I think). So it's not a good solution for most use cases today. But perhaps it is for you or some readers of the future.

Update: Browser support seems to be [even worse today](http://caniuse.com/#search=seamless), so this isn't a solution today or in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can access the contents inside iframe 
using the following syntax:

```
$('iframe.webform-frame').contents().find('h5').css("color","#f00");
```

Comment: This only works if the iframe is on the same domain as the main page