# youtube embedded player download video as mp4 button attributes

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

How do you control the attributes, such as position and size, for the "download video as mp4" button that shows up when you embed a youtube video.  For example:

```
<iframe width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

I checked the google developers page and searched around, but didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To style/position it you would need to target it in CSS and apply properties to it there. I would recommend checking out w3schools if you are knew to CSS.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of how to use css to style elements.  However, when you embed a youtube player, the button shows up and there appears to be no way to access its attributes.

Comment: @user3080392 in that case check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316562/style-content-within-an-iframe

Comment: It turns out that my browser was running a youtube downloader plugin that I was unaware of.  Once I disabled it, the download button no longer showed up.  I was thinking that the download button was a feature of the youtube embed.