# Hide div inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I will ask a question first.

Is it possible to hide contents inside an iframe, BUT! I don't have any control to the iframe's src.

Now, if it's possible...

For example, I have this:

```
<iframe src="https://google.co.in"></iframe>
```

and I want to edit the word "**India**" in *https://google.co.in* to "**Egypt**" (All these are examples)

Is that possible? and if yes can you tell me any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316562/style-content-within-an-iframe

Comment: It depends. But in your example with google then answer is no as you will run into cross domain issues. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe . You would need to either use a proxy or fetch the contents and display them in another manner.

Comment: @Shnibble - this isn't what I wanted. also there's a lot of questions like that but I still can't figure it.

Comment: Guys, a code like `$("#mesaframe").contents().find("room-link").hide();` but this isn't working for me.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you are asking then? If you don't have access to the src of an iFrame then chances are you can't do whatever it is you want to do with the contents of the iFrame. Even if you find some sort of hacky way I can't imagine the owner of the actual src would be happy with you manipulating their content. Maybe provide the actual example of what you are trying to do for clarification?